# PHP on Ubuntu autoload_register and namespacing issue

Tags: php, ubuntu, namespaces, spl-autoload-register

I have a problem here. I have created the namespace for all classes. previously i was using windows 7 to develop current app, everything is fine. now i just moved to ubuntu, the problem comes.

index.php

```
spl_autoload_extensions(".php");
/*spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    require __DIR__ . '/../' . $class . '.php';
});*/
//provided i have tried the above method, which works on windows 7 but not Ubuntu
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    require '/../' . $class . '.php';
});

//for your info, i do this
//require "../resources/library/Config.php";
//it works, no error

use resources\library as LIB;
use resources\dal as DAL;

//instantiation
$config = new LIB\Config();
print_r($config->fbKey());
```

i got this error

```
PHP Warning:  require(../resources\\library\\Config.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/user/dir1/dir2/index.php
```

i cannot find the error. hope you guys can help me with this. any question don hesitate to comment i will edit. thanks in advance.

**UPDATE - Extra Info**

PHP version 5.4.6

**LATEST UPDATE**

any idea how to solve this without using str_replace ? JULP and MOONWAVE have the answer!

Comment: I'm guessing it's a problem with case-sensitive file names, or file permissions. That's usually where problems creep in when porting from Windows to *nix

Comment: No choice: you need to replace all backslashes in the name of the class, due to namespace, by slashes.

Comment: What are you using str_replace anyway? Why would you have `\\` in the `$class` variable to begin with?

Comment: @MikeBrant , as they answered, i tried to use str_replace and it works, if i don, i get this error (error-> \\library\\Config.php). btw, what you mean "have \` in the $class` variable to begin with"? which slash? if i don put the slash to begin with, i get this error (public_html/..resources). for your info, resources folder is outside root folder(public_html)

Comment: @julp, this is very sad. let's see what others say

Comment: Like I said, this is what `spl_autoload_register` (without argument) does internally (since PHP 5.3.3). See [#51991](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=51991) and [its code](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_4/ext/spl/php_spl.c#253).

Comment: moonwave and julp both have the correct answer, since moonwave has more karma, let's give some karma to julp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which PHP version do you use? (in PHP < 5.3.3, default spl_autoload_register was not namespace aware - I mean \ was not replaced by / on Unix systems)

In your code, try to replace:

```
require __DIR__ . '/../' . $class . '.php';
```

By:

```
require __DIR__ . '/../' . str_replace('\\', '/', $class) . '.php';
```

=> Always use slashes in path, they work everywhere. Backslashes, don't. And don't forget filenames are case sensitive on Unix systems, the opposite of Windows.

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem with your directory separator, as it is different in Win and Unix.

To be consistent, you should update your autoload function:

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    require '/../' . str_replace("\\", DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $class) . '.php';
});
```

EDIT: the solution is [pretty wide accepted](https://github.com/symfony/ClassLoader/blob/master/UniversalClassLoader.php) in production environments.

Comment: moon, question updated, u have any idea to solve this problem without using str_replace? or i need to change my code?

Comment: You use `string_replace`, period. What's the problem in using it?

Comment: +1 for the great answer and the link. moon, thanks, i have looked at the link you posted. btw, is this method works on all unix? because this ubuntu is my dev machine, after that i might be hosting it, i not sure what type or linux/unix it is.

Comment: Yeah, directory separator is the same on all unix distros. You can't do much about the replacement because both symbols [unix filesystem separator and PHP namespace separator] are not configurable [luckily!].

Answer (score 0):

You should familiarize yourself with the use of PHP's `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` constant if you are going to be doing cross-platform development.

The error message there should tell you all you need to know.  You are not generating proper LINUX file paths.

Comment: mike, i not sure which part of my code is the issue, i don feel like using str_replace, and i believe ubuntu can work with namespace without the use of str_replace, you have any idea?